# Get Current UTC Date and Time

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Using the `Now()` AMPscript function will give the current system date and time, but is there an easy way to get the current UTC date? I don't see anything like a `UtcNow()` function, but that's what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native function for this, but as UTC is always 6 hours ahead of CST (as there is no Daylight Savings Time included to alter it) you can do a simple DateAdd function around it to get the UTC date/time. All Server time is always in CST, which means with that DateAdd it will always correctly adjust.

```
%%[ SET @nowUTC = DateAdd(Now(), 6, "H") ]%%
```